# Criar link baseado em uma entrada do usuário

Tags: html, redirecionamento

Estou tentando criar uma página - que pode ser em qualquer linguagem, mas precisa ser armazenada em um arquivo único - para que um usuário digite seu login e a partir daí, seja criado um link para prosseguir a um site.

Esse site recebe o usuário em seu link, assim: https://site.com.br/usuario=***LOGIN***&empresa

O que consegui fazer foi link de redirecionamento estático:

```
    <script>
    var login = "loginname";
    </script>

    <a href="#" onclick="window.open('site.com.br/usuario=' + login + '&empresa')" target"_blank">Go to site</a>
```

Quero fazer uma caixa de texto com um botão ao lado para que ao clicar, o usuário seja redirecionado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algo bem simples e em javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
function Login(){
var username=document.login.username.value;

if (username!="") { 
window.location="http://site.com.br?usuario="+username;
}

}

</script>

<form name=login>

<input type="text" name="username" size="9">
<input type="button" value="Entrar" onClick="Login()">

</form>
```

Comment: Cara, era isso! Muito obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente.